# Writing formulas in first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Let $\sigma = \{+, \cdot\}$ be a signature with binary function symbols and let $\mathcal{N} = (\mathbb{N}, +^\mathcal{N}, \cdot^\mathcal{N})$ be a structure with the normal $+$ und $\cdot$ operations. Give for each $\varphi_{i}$ a fitting formula:
>
> $\varphi_0(\mathcal{N}) = \{ 0 \}$.
>
> $\varphi_1(\mathcal{N}) = \{ 1 \}$.
>
> $\varphi_2(\mathcal{N}) = \{ 2k, k \in \mathbb{N} \}$.
>
> $\varphi_3(\mathcal{N}) = \{ (x, y), x<y \}$.

For $\varphi_0$ I have  $\varphi_0(x) := \forall y (y + x = y)$, since the free variable $x$ can only be $0$.

$\varphi_1 (x) := \exists y (y \cdot x = y \land \lnot \varphi_0(y))$.

Here I'm saying that the free variable $x$ has to be $1$ but $y$ cannot be $0$.

For $\varphi_2(x)$ I have first defined $\varphi_2'(x)$ with $\varphi_2'(\mathcal{N}) = \{2 \}$:

$\varphi_2'(x) = \exists y \exists z (y + z = x \land \varphi_1(y) \land \varphi_1(z))$

$\varphi_2(x) = \exists y \forall z (y \cdot z = x \land \varphi'_2(y))$

Here I'm saying that $y$ must be $2$, forcing $x$ to be even.

I haven't been able to come up with a formula for $\varphi_3$, all I know is that it has to have $2$ free variables and would really appreciate any hints.

Can someone please check my work?

Comment: Why did you delete your first question, now highlighted, and not edit to improve it, but only improve it in a repost?

Comment: @amWhy I haven't deleted any questions.

Comment: Well, then I guess a class mate or such asked only the question (in grey here), without work.  Thanks for showing your effort, and narrowing your question! :-)

Comment: @Katja I did find a small mistake and have edited my answer. Just letting you know here as well because I am not sure if you get notified of an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solutions so far are almost* correct. An easier solution for $\varphi_2(x)$ would be $\exists y(x = y + y)$.

For $\varphi_3(x, y)$ you can use that $x < y$ precisely when there is some nonzero $z$ such that $x + z = y$.

---

*: I noticed that you have one wrong quantifier in $\varphi_2(x)$. The $\forall z$ should be $\exists z$. Because otherwise that formula reads "$x = 2 \cdot z$ for all $z$", which can of course not happen.